# Каковы синонимы к слову "благодать"?

Tags: лексика

Каковы синонимы к слову "благодать"?

Answer (score 1):

Блаженство, наслаждение.
Если, конечно, речь не идет о Божьей благодати. Тогда - благословение, покровительство.

Answer (score 1):

Вспомните Ивана Васильевича: "Лепота"!